# JMenuBar and a item array - bad idea?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, menubar

I've poked around the internet a bit and my lack of findings makes me guess yes, but would using an array to fill the items of a JMenuBar be a less than good idea? I also think yes since whenever you wonder "is this a bad idea?" it usually is. However, my newness to programming makes me question if I know a bad from good idea at this point.

Originally I thought it'd be good since most of the time arrays are beneficial and save space. However, when I began thinking through the code I realized it wasn't exactly practical. To start if you do all the items in one array you are trying to count to figure out which number goes with which menu. 
I suppose you can do an array for the items in each menu, but if you decide to change an item to a menu so you can have sub-menus you're back to which-number-is-it issues.

Edit: It also makes creating and adding the items and adding action listeners much quicker

Opinions?

Comment: I would say the answer is yes and no.  For example, if you were building a "Recents" menu, then an array or some kind of `List` would be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go with no. although it looks like it would save alot of time, and is a very good idea, i'm afraid that it will not work.

I am saying this because the `JMenu`, or `JMenuBar` 'add' method is only good for use with single `JMenus` or `JMenuItems`. I have tried and I got an error saying that it is used with `JMenu` not `JMenu[]`.

If you would like, it might be possible to make a class that adds arrays to `JComponents`, by going through each array item until null, and adding it seperatly. That will be alot of extra work, but it might just pay of for speed and efficiency.